# Can you be literal about non-literal things?

Tags: meaning, figures-of-speech

I know many hackles have been raised over the misuse of the word literal.

Let's say there are a couple of mobsters talking about a third guy who has made a minor mistake, and jokingly one says, "I'm going to fit him for some cement shoes."  Meaning he's angry, but not homicidal. Perhaps he makes this joke often.  He does not intend to kill him.

If he actually wanted to kill him he might say, "I'm *literally* going to fit him for some cement shoes", meaning take my non-literal euphemism for killing literally.

Beyond this there is a third level of literality where the very nature of the euphemism is taken into question, not a euphemism for murder, but an actual pair of shoes fashioned from cement.

My question is if someone says, "I'm *literally* going to fit him for some cement shoes", are both interpretations potentially correct? That he's not joking about killing him, and that he's going to make him some heavy footwear?

Comment: Firstly, I don't think you'd use *literally* along with a euphemism, or I might chuckle at it.

Comment: +1: I do think this is a worthy question, deeper than it may appear at first glance.

Comment: Only if you're not using *literally* literally.

Comment: A good example, and a bit older, is "literally have kittens!"  it's just a fact that "literal" means less these days!  :O

Comment: I don't think it's possible to give a factual answer to this question, since it's asking whether things are *correct*. That would be a value judgement, not a statement about reality, and there isn't a clear consensus in this case among English language users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I'm literally going to fit him for cement shoes."

This would mean more than simply "I intend to kill him." It would mean "I intend to encase his feet in cement and throw him in the river [or lake, or ocean, etc.], thereby killing him".

That said, the sort of person who would actually kill someone in this way — who would speak those words in a literal sense — is someone who is not too worried about violating convention and would very likely not be fussy about speech and grammar; he might easily mean "literal" in its corrupted "figurative" sense.

**EDIT**

I see from the comments that some people insist on carrying any expression of literalness out to six decimal places; in other words, that for a thing to be described as being "literally" some state or condition, the state or condition must be exact to that amount. Or more.

I disagree.

The act of "fitting someone for cement shoes" (or overshoes, or boots) refers to a very specific way of killing someone. It is a figurative description, but one which describes a real action: putting someone's feet in a tub of cement, letting it harden, and then hurling the poor unfortunate to his death by drowning. To that extent, I insist that someone could be "literally fitted for cement overshoes" if they were killed in the manner that the trope suggests. The expression does not cover murder by gunfire, garotte, stiletto, or poison, but it does cover that particular case. Literally.

Let's look at another case:

> I'm going to literally beat you to a pulp.

Now, the literal-minded may insist that the word "literally" may not be used there, because "to a pulp" is a figure of speech. But if they do, they first have to explain exactly what degree of beating qualifies or doesn't qualify as producing pulp. A mashed nose or smashed ear or other severe deformation may be construed as a "pulping," and if one allows that at some point pulp is produced then the argument becomes trivial and pedantic and not worth the trouble. The objection is reduced to the state of an advertising claim for orange juice: no pulp, some pulp, lots of pulp.

I believe that if someone threatens to "literally beat me to a pulp" I face severe damage to my person. Whether or not that qualifies in some minds as "pulp" is irrelevant.

Now, we have to look at this on a scale. The guideline to apply here would involve whether the action or state described as "literal" does contain actual parts of truth ("some pulp") or none at all ("no pulp"). If someone says

> It literally made my head explode.

we may poke fun at them by saying their head has made a splendid recovery since them, because they seem to be talking out of it. In that case, the figurative expression (even though it does describe a state of abject bewilderment or consternation) is rendered ridiculous because it is too far from reality to be considered literal in any sense ("no pulp").

To sum up: This is all a matter of degree. Some figurative expressions, if they refer to actual actions or conditions that can be produced, may be modified by some form of the adjective "literal" — even to the literal-minded. (Hey, did we agree on what a *mind* is yet? Literally?)

Comment: Ah, but encasing one's feet in cement is not literally fitting for cement shoes! Anything short of actually having the person try on a pair of shoes made of cement would not be literal! And who said anything (literally) about killing the person? ;)

Comment: **"I'm literally going to fit him for cement shoes."**
`.......`
_this means more than simply "I intend to kill him." It means "I intend to encase his feet in cement and throw him in the river [or lake, or ocean, etc.], thereby killing him"_ 
`.......`
Okay, but we can get more literal than that!  It means, "I'm going to throw him into the river with cement shoes, but first we'll go to Home Depot to buy custom-sized molds for his feet!"

Comment: Your summation brings up a good question. What if there is no actual producible conditions because the words don't have an agreed upon meaning. _A literal meeting of the minds_ is ambiguous because what is a mind? We've just veered into the Mind-Body problem.

Comment: @Sam: Good point.

Answer (score 2):

*Literal* has an absolute meaning, and if you accept that absolute meaning then "I'm literally going to fit him for cement shoes" means only, literally, that -- to measure the person's feet so that you know what size cement shoes he would wear.

However, people use *literally* in a non-literal sense quite often, just for emphasis:

> She was literally tearing her hair out.

(...where the subject was not, literally, tearing her hair out)

So we can accept that, in everyday speech, *literal* has varying levels of absoluteness.

You've identified a situation where a figure of speech is layered on top of other meanings:

- "Fit him for concrete shoes" could imply...
- "Encase his feet in concrete and throw him in water" could imply...
- "Kill him" (either using the actual method above, or some other method) could imply...
- Scold him seriously

... and you want to know whether adding *literally* strips away one layer, or all of them.

The answer is that if we take the absolute interpretation of *literal*, then it strips away all layers. As I showed above, it would mean to measure him up and find out what size concrete shoes he would take.

However if we take the less absolute interpretation of *literal*, then the meaning becomes **ambiguous**. We simply can't tell how many layers of interpretation *literally* removes from the meaning. We just have to use our knowledge of the context to make an educated guess.

Comment: Yes. Are we stripping away one layer or all of them? And for those using an absolute sense of literally, what would be their mechanism for stripping away only one layer? Does it all come down to interpretation?

Comment: English simply isn't as precise as you would like it to be. I don't think the mechanism you're looking for exists -- other than to painstakingly explain exactly what you mean sentence by sentence. It really does all come down to interpretation.

Comment: @Charles oops. Fixing.

Answer (score 2):

The facts of the matter are ..

1) literal used to mean, "literal" (exactly, truly, 100%)

but

2) since perhaps the 1950s (?) it has simply been used as a general strengthener - a meaningless slang emphasiser. (Not unlike a **swear word** - a completely pointless addition to a sentence which, literally (joke), does not in the slightest, in fact, change the meaning of the sentence at all, in any way.)

It's possibly the case that usage (2) is, indeed, the more popular - perhaps even the hugely more popular - usage now.

Really that's all there is to it. This can be "annoying" if you don't like words changing meaning - if it's annoying to you when people use words like "decimate" incorrectly. But point (2) is in fact what has happened in the world - so that's it!

Comment: One way in which people don't like words changing meaning can claw back a bit of dignity, is to look at spoken use (and reported speech) vs "formal" written use. The people using "literally" as a general strengthener might hold off from using it in certain registers. "I'm literally gutted by what's happening in Ukraine, I had to cancel my holiday", happens. "Reuters: President Obama appeared literally shaken at the update from Ukraine Sunday" not so much. So you can (if you're that bothered) pounce on those registers as being more important to the "real" meaning than others :-)

Comment: ... actually I wonder if "literally" being used more precisely than as a *completely* general pointless intensifier. Is it actually being used that way mostly when the speaker knows what they're saying is figurative, making it all the more infuriating to literalists? That is, maybe speakers say "literally" to cancel out any impression that because they're speaking figuratively they aren't sincere. So "I'm literally gutted" means "I really am upset", for fear that "I'm gutted" alone would be taken to mean "blah blah trivial complaint blah blah".

Comment: Steve in answer to your second astute comment: if you glance at popular culture I'm afraid I'd take the bitter view that, almost certainly, 70%? of people using "literally" ("I'm literally going to kill that fucker" etc), in fact, quite literally, just literally would not be able to state the dictionary definition or any definition of the word; I feel they'd interpret it as **you really mean it**.  So "kill the fucker" in fact means "I'm incredibly angry at him".  (it does not literally mean "will murder".)  IMO in the cloudy mind of the person saying "literally kill the fucker".....

Comment: ... what they mean is rather than "I'm incredibly angry at him", they mean "I'm incredibly angry at him and I really mean that truly, I emphasise the truth of how much 'I'm incredibly angry at him'."  In short, no, IMO nobody (that will never get not funny, BTW) has a clue of the actual meaning of literal any more.

Comment: BTW a related curiosity; I'm trying to find ANY OTHER WORD which is a synonym of literal as in the sentence "I am using word X literally."  It's quite confusing trying to say "I am using literal literally" and there is, I believe, no synonym, at all, nuthin', for "literal"!  (perhaps "in the exact traditional and more historic dictionary meaning of the word" .. I guess.)  Maybe "dictinoarywise" would work.

Comment: (In other words, IMO, in the usage: "I'm literally _action_" then IMO (a) in fact the _action_ is physically meaningless (having kittens, tear strips off, etc) and in fact expresses a **personal position** (I'm angry, I'm excited) and then (b) the "literally" means nothing more than "very" (I'm very angry, I'm very excited).)

Comment: Since perhaps the **1750s**, not 1950s literally has been used as an intensifier. See http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002611.html

Comment: fantastic info !! @bdsl

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can be, but first you have to use precisely or truthfully or else someone will think what you're saying is figurative. Even in a context of war someone saying "The Gun fire literally blew his head off!" could mean

- The Gun fire disassembled his head and pushed it off or in reality blew his head off
- The Gun fire decapitated him.
- The Gun fire hit his head most likely killing him.
- The Gun fire surprised him or terrified him.

depending on the context even if the person was missing people might not think definition 1 they might even think definition 4 or most likely 3 even in war.

Either way definitions other then 1 are hyperbole, but it's not incorrect to use literally or actually as figuratively https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/misuse-of-literally  people might use truthfully in this sense too.

Instead of literally, actually, or truthfully, you can use words  like simply, justifiably, truly, in actual fact, factually, accurately, in reality, unmistakably, clearly, and other synonyms here https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/literal , although simply or truly may be used figuratively.

Comment: This answer would be improved by citing references that support your primary claim.

Comment: Okay here's one https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/misuse-of-literally.

Comment: Literally has changed to mean figuratively too.

Comment: In a fight or battle hyperbole is used i.e we literally got beat to a pulp @Davo

Comment: Sure. And "decimated" is usually understood as devastated, not just 10% losses. However, I'm not discussing what your answer is, but how it's presented. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read about [answering](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just did and my answer is find I explained what I meant in a literal clear to understand way, so what's the problem preventing upvotes?